# Google Calendar notification are silent

Tags: notifications, google-apps, silent-mode

The notification show up on time but since yesterday the phone remains silent. Before there was a little sound with the notifcation.

I have checked the volume of the phone, the blocking mode is off, the notifcation sound in settings/sound and the settings in Google Calendar. 
There are all set corrctly but still my notification are silent.

Notifications from other apps still make the sound Calenda should do.

Any idea how to solve this?

phone: samsung S3, KitKat, rooted

Comment: I just went through all of the settings on my S3 but didn't really see anything that could inadvertently disable just the Calendar notification. Do you have a custom notification tone selected in the Settings->General? I assume you tried a reboot?

Comment: Thanks for your time @paulmz, Yes I did a reboot. Yes I also have a custom notification tone  selected  in  the  Settings->General. I found a way to solve  that by uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to uninstall Google Calendar and to reinstall it. 
Be sure that your event are sync with Google so that you don't loose any data.