# Amazon notifications are silent

Tags: notifications, settings, audio

So I'm looking out for an Amazon delivery I don't want to miss, and the Amazon Shopping app puts up the message in my phone's notification area saying my package is 6 stops away, view it on a map.

But the notification makes no sound, so chances are I don't notice.

Similar to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127403/google-calendar-notification-are-silent) about Google Calendar notifications misbehaving in the same way. There are no answers to that one to date, and the person fixed it eventually by reinstalling the app. But I've already tried installing the Amazon Shopping app on three different Android devices (Samsung phone, Motorola phone and Amazon Fire tablet). On all three devices the issue is the same.

I've checked all the related settings I can find, both general Android settings and those within the app.

How is it possible the Android operating system can let the user configure audible notifications and it all works fine except for one app?

Comment: If it behaves the same on every device & Android version and independent of the user account, then there's a possibility that the developer didn't let the notification play the notification sound. Weird, but possible, since notification by default doesn't play any sound, and the developer must set the code for it. Some more things to check: how about the Amazon's app "Notification" setting from "App Info", and do you use "Do Not Disturb" mode?

Comment: @AndrewT. interesting to know the developer could do that. I agree it would be a weird thing to do, at least for a notification like this one which by its nature is meant to get your attention and not just hang around unnoticed till you next happen to look. (Maybe I'll just have to write an app myself, to monitor Amazon alerts and alert me!) To reply, the app's Notification settings are Allow, and Show Silently is turned off. DND I use sometimes yes, but not at the times in question.
Could folks reading this please comment as to whether or not they get audible Amazon Delivery notifications?